# how to call a function from another file?

Tags: python

Sorry basic question I'm sure but I can't seem to figure this out.

Say I have this program , the file is called `pythonFunction.py`:

```
def function():
   return 'hello world'

if __name__=='__main__':
   print function()
```

How can I call it in another program?
I tried:

```
import pythonFunction as pythonFunction
print pythonFunction.function
```

Instead of 'hello world', I get  ...I have done this in the past by making the first file a class, but I was wondering how to import the function correctly?  If it helps, in my real file, I am printing a dictionary

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to print the result of calling the function, rather than the function itself:

```
print pythonFunction.function()
```

Additionally, rather than `import pythonFunction as pythonFunction`, you can omit the `as` clause:

```
import pythonFunction
```

If it's more convenient, you can also use `from...import`:

```
from pythonFunction import function
print function() # no need for pythonFunction.
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I call the if __name__=='__main__': or is the only way to call it from the function? its fine, but when I do it I get errors about variables not being global, I can change it but was just wondering

Comment: @Lostsoul: Unfortunately, you cannot call the `if __name__ == '__main__'` section from another module. What many modules employ is having a `main` function, and all the `if __name__ == '__main__'` section does is call it.

Comment: Actually, it is possible to call the `if __name__ == '__main__'` section with the execfile() buildin function.