# How to call a python function in another file

Tags: python

How can I call a python function from another file?

I read 
[how to call a function from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701646/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-file)

And following what is suggested, but I think it does not work for me because 
both myscript.py and myaotherscript.py uses variables likes 'argv', 'args'

I want to call in myscript.py

```
def main(argv):
    myanotherscript.main(argv)
```

Comment: Which specific suggestion are you following?

Comment: There are many possible situations where what you have written would work fine. You need to provide a minimal example including contents of both files and where they are located (i.e., in what directories). Also, what error (or bad behavior) do you get?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: Where are the files located? How does your code look like? What is the observed behavior? What did you expect to see? This question hardly contains any relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me:

File1.py:

```
import file2
import sys

def main(argv):
    file2.main(argv)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

File2.py:

```
def main(argv):
    # do something useful...
```

Comment: This answer is only missing a link: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the argv (and possible argc) to your other script's main method.

If the input from `myscript.py`'s `main` is something that would be accepted by `myanotherscript.py`'s `main` method, this would be fine.

However, you should be asking yourself if this is what you really need. Alternatively you could simply construct another list of arguments to pass. The argument names only have method scope so you can reuse names across methods (so long as you don't declare them as globals).