# Python Quiz Issues, Can I import a whole "defined function" from another file?

Tags: function, python-3.x

I'm building a quiz with Python. So the code looks like this.

```
def animal_quiz():
    # do something

def city_quiz():
  # do something

def math_quiz():
   # do something

topic = raw_input('Do you want to answer questions on animals or capital cities or math? Type animal, city or math')

if topic == 'animal':
   animal_quiz()

elif topic == 'city':
     city_quiz()
```

But what if I want to define the function of the whole "animal quiz" in a different file and then just import that file.. is that possible? How?

Comment: Python provides a mechanism called "importing" to do this.  Any basic Python tutorial should cover this.

Comment: Yes, in fact it should be part of any decent tutorial. For instance https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules. I think you'll find it faster to go through the tutorial than ask!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to call a function from another file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701646/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible

```
from my_file import func
func()
```

or

```
import my_file
my_file.func()
```

Search for python modules

Comment: Thanks a lot taoufik.. that helped me a lot.